# How to Access Windows Container from a Remote Host using Docker command line tool

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, windows-container

I try to access Windows Container daemon from a remote host using Docker command line tool with parameter like this:

```
--tlsverify
--tlscacert="/home/kamit/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem"
--tlscert="/home/kamit/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem"
--tlskey="/home/kamit/.docker/machine/certs/key.pem"
-H=tcp://104.131.102.147:2376
```

How do I configure Windows Container to make that happen?

Comment: Try `-H=tcp://0.0.0.0:2376`, and set your local `DOCKER_HOST` env variable to the ip of the remote server.